# Express static serve with dynamic subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, subdomain

I'm trying to get express static working with dynamic subdomain.

Basically `http://ratty-doll-4811.localhost:3333` this subdomain is dynamic, and I load static folder based on this subdomain.

My issue is index.html loads but app.js which is in the same directory as index.html, doesn't load.

```
const subdomain = require('subdomain');
var app = Express()
app.use(subdomain({ base : 'localhost', removeWWW : true }));
app.get('/subdomain/:url', function(req, res, next) {
  app.use('', Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/public' })
});
```

Here is the error: [image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing a Github repo URL of this project?

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically call `app.use()` because that will just build up route handlers over and over and they will accumulate indefinitely and be in force for all future requests.  You can however, get the request handler from `express.static()` and call the request handler yourself dynamically.

I don't follow exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but this will show you how you can call it dynamically and then act differently based on whether it found a match of not.

```
// get express.static() handler
let staticHandler = Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

app.get('/subdomain/:url', function(req, res, next) {
  staticHandler(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      // it only gets here if the staticHandler didn't find a match and send a response
      res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname + '/public' })
  });
});
```

Comment: @westdabestdb - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.